# How to equate two different objects of class of third party Jars, If a third party class does not have equal methods(we don't know))

Tags: java

How to equate two different objects of class of  third party Jars, If a third party class does not have equal method implementations,We don't know any thing about that class

Comment: Welcome to stack Overflow. Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) are some useful links on how to complete a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every Java class extends `java.lang.Object` which contains a method `.equals(Object object)` for comparison on another object. This method returns true if and only if the variables being compared are pointing to the same object instance in memory (unless the method is overridden).

If you simply want to check equality of two objects in java, use this method.

If the method is being overridden (be careful), then it depends how it is implemented to know it's functionality, because this starts to have an interesting number of issues, such as:

1. Can subtypes be equal to their parent types?
2. Can different types with the same fields be equal? In this case, do you compare statics?
3. For a list/array field, does the list/array need to be the same instance, or just the elements within the list?
4. For any collection, does order matter?
5. When you compare fields, are you checking instance equality every time, or will the "reflection equality" check be recursive?

And I'm sure there's more to consider.

In terms of implementation, that's up to you. A utility class? A generic EqualsBuilder of sorts? Extending each class to override their equals methods? Etc.

Either way, when you stop comparing places in memory, you're in possibly unsafe territory if you're not careful.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `EqualsBuilder` from apache.commons.lang to compare two objects using reflection api:

```
EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(Object, Object)
```

take a look [Here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say, especially if you do not know anything about the objects.

If possible i would suggest you to:

- Create a wrapper around the object
- Use the getters of the source object for equality checks, implement equals/hashcode in the wrapper
- Copy the data from the getters into the wrapper (if the returned values of the getters are not immutable)
- If possible make the wrapper final, will save you lots of trouble when adding it to a set/map (a changing hashcode of an object that is already in a set/map will break it)

Try to keep it simple. Do not relay on anything you are not sure about.